# Can I remove the category labels (social, promotions etc) from Gmail entirely?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-categories

I've no intention of ever using these labels, but there doesn't seem to be anyway to remove them.

It's frustrating as it really clutters up the labels dropdown box, with 5 completely superfluous labels.

Comment: You can hide them, which will effectively remove them, but they're still used in the background.

Comment: See also: [Can I avoid using Gmail's category tabs and revert to the old interface?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/65784/354)

Comment: Thank you! Adding the rules into my ad blocker removed them from the drop down too! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can do it easily. just enter settings and hide them all

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have this set at the moment, but the labels still appear in the dropdown when selecting a label :(

Comment: @Nick I've updated my answer. see it now